# How can I get the current list/library Name in SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

How can I get the current list/library Name in SharePoint Designer workflow? I have searched all the lookup options, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method I've used in SP2007 is to have a hidden column in my list to store information.  Then on the NewForm, I create a hidden field that is going to store the data I want.  Then using the IIS server variable URL, you can manipulate the value using XSLT string-before and string-after functions to extract the list name.  This is then stored in the list item itself and can be used in a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring this full circle, some third party workflow tools have this built in.  We have Nintex Workflow available and as part of the standard pieces of data, it knows the list name and other pieces of information like item url all available as default metadata/variables that can be injected into workflow emails.

Prior to having this functionality, I had to go with the above route.